# Is there a mistake in this illustration?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

In chapter 14.2, page 620, in "Big Java" (International 4th edition), by Cay Horstmann, it is shown how to implement a linked list. The add method of the listIterator looks like this:

```
public void add(Object element) {
            if(position == null) {
                addFirst(element);
                position = first;
            } else {
                Node newNode = new Node();
                newNode.data = element;
                newNode.next = position.next;
                position.next = newNode;
                position = newNode;
            }
            previous = position;
}
```

The corresponding illustration looks like the one I added below. The first one is before "newNode" has been added, and the second one is after. Can someone tell me if there is a mistake in the second picture. Shouldn't the fields "previous" and "position" point to the same object after a call to "add(Object element)"? The top picture is before and the bottom one is after insertion.[image: Before Insertion]
[image: After Insertion]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it the code seems wrong and `previous` should have been set to `position` **before** it was actually changed.

Something like this:

```
public void add(Object element) {
            previous = position;
            if(position == null) {
                addFirst(element);
                position = first;
            } else {
                Node newNode = new Node();
                newNode.data = element;
                newNode.next = position.next;
                position.next = newNode;
                position = newNode;
            }
}
```

That would match the intended outcome of the second picture

Comment: Ok. And the picture is also wrong or is it correct?